# How to Highlight a search text in a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a `Textbox` and a drop down list in my webpage. when I enter a text in `TextBox`  and  its `TextChanged` event is fired items containing that text are loaded into another dropdown list below.I had set dropdown state to Openloadondemand to `true`.
I need to highlight that search text inside the dropdown list items only, but I am unable to do so.

I have got codes from [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/search-records-in-gridview-and.html) and I tried to implement it in my page.

Codes are

Style.css

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight 
{
text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;color:black; background:yellow;

}
```

cs code

```
 protected void txtItemCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     //my code
     ddl_ItemName.OpenDropDownOnLoad = true;
     HighlightText(itemtext);
   }

 public string HighlightText(string InputTxt)
   {
     Regex RegExp = new Regex(InputTxt.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(),     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     return RegExp.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords));
   }
 public string ReplaceKeyWords(Match m)
   {
    return ("<span class=highlight>" + m.Value + "</span>");
   }
```

My Design  is

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="label">Item Code : </td>
     <td style="width: 180px;" class="field">
       <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtItemCode" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
        ontextchanged="txtItemCode_TextChanged" >
       </telerik:RadTextBox>
     </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="label">Item Name : </td>
   <td class="field">
     <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl_ItemName" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
       EmptyMessage="Choose an Item"
       EnableLoadOnDemand="True" MarkFirstMatch="true" 
       onselectedindexchanged="ddl_ItemName_SelectedIndexChanged" >               
     </telerik:RadComboBox>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are trying to implement an auto-complete text field which shows a user a dropdown of options to choose from. The keyword query that a user entered is always bolded in every list item in the dropdown.

On the basis of the above understanding, what you really want is to ensure that your dropdown of auto-complete options wraps a `span` or any HTML element around the keyword that a user has entered in the text field.

See the following example:

HTML (The unordered list below is dynamically generated by JavaScripted on TextChanged)

```
<input type="text" value="Something">
<ul id="auto-complete">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span>Something</span> Borrowed</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">There's <span>something</span> about Mary</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span>Something</span>'s Gotta Give</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#auto-complete li span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Check the following JSFiddle to see the styling in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hadynz/AE7TE/

Comment: I have 2 separate controls... One text box and another drop downlist in my page... Here event is fired in TextChangedEvent

Comment: Just read your updated your question. It seems that all your auto-completed options in your dropdown use `#span.highlight` to surround the keyword that a user has typed. This means all that your missing is a CSS declaration of `#span.highlight { font-weight: bold }`